# Keep rows in a 2d array where a column's subarray contains a specific value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, sub-array

Having the following array:

```
var products = [
    { title: "Product One", categories: ["one", "two"] },
    { title: "Product Two", categories: ["two", "three"] },
    { title: "Product Three", categories: ["three", "four"] }
];
```

How can I filter the array (I only want products which have category "two") so I get the desired result:

```
[
    { title: "Product One", categories: ["one", "two"] },
    { title: "Product Two", categories: ["two", "three"] }
]
```

Comment: php arrays look a bit different.

Comment: Try using - array_filter  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: What have you tried? Add some examples of what you have tried before looking for someone to code for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$product = '[
    { title: "Product One", categories: ["one", "two"] },
    { title: "Product Two", categories: ["two", "three"] },
    { title: "Product Three", categories: ["three", "four"] }
]';

$productArray = json_decode($product);

foreach($productArray as $key => $value)
{
     if(!in_array('two', $value['categories']))
         unset($productArray[$key]);
}

$productJson = json_encode($productArray);

echo $productJson;
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this solution! I know that it wasn't correct JSON, but I only wanted to clear which data I use. Furthermore I tried array_filter but couldn't get it to work.. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Even after correcting the malformed json string, this answer does not work: https://3v4l.org/k84BM

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
products = products.filter(function(item){
               return item.categories.indexOf('two') > -1;
           });
```

PHP:

```
$products = array_filter(
    json_decode($products),
    function($val) {
        return in_array('two', $val->categories);
    }
);
```

But, first you need to correct your json input by double quoting the keys. Below is corrected:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Product One",
        "categories": [
            "one",
            "two"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Product Two",
        "categories": [
            "two",
            "three"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Product Three",
        "categories": [
            "three",
            "four"
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use array_filter http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php :

print_r(array_filter($array, "value"));